# Incremental Search across Projectile project

Tags: projectile, isearch

How do I perform `isearch` over a whole projectile project, so that I can cycle through all occurrences of a string? This would be equivalent to `multi-isearch-file` for all files in the projectile project.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend `projectile-ag` for this. Works very well and is somewhat faster than `isearch`

Answer (score 0):

Projectile has built-in support for searching through project files with grep (or similar utils like ack or ag). See for example `projectile-grep`.

If you want to use `multi-isearch-file`, this seems to work:

```
(defun projectile-multi-isearch-files ()
  (interactive)
  (multi-isearch-files (projectile-current-project-files)))
```